# Generating touch events from a background service in android

Tags: android

I can understand the security reasons behind not allowing a background service to dispatch touch events to the app (any app. that does not belong the context of the service) that is running in the foreground. But there are some apps available in the playstore that can be used to access a remote device. How are those apps generating touch events?
An example of such app. is Optia
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.optim.optiasmsng&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one hint in the system requirements:

```
It must be equipped with original Samsung firmware
```

I would guess that it has been built withing the Android build tree (to enable it to use methods marked with @hide too) and given a user ID that has system permissions (which regular apps doesn't have).

Comment: @salalerer : I did not get what you meant by 'built within the android build tree'. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There are methods in the source code tree of Android marked with the annotation \@hide. This prevents these symbols from being exported which in turn prevents apps from using them. If you download the source code of Android and put your code in the 3rd party area (like Samsung do when they create a new ROM for one of their phones) you can access these methods marked with @hide in your code.

Comment: @selelerer: thanks for the clarification. But Optia is developed by Optim corporation. How can they possibly access these methods while other developers can't??

Comment: They can download the build tree just like anyone else, it's open source. The problem is to use the a user ID which Samsung ROM gives extra (run-time) permissions. Maybe they get cooperation from Samsung for that.